# Как в цикле forEach обратиться к следующей итерации?

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach

Делаю переключение блоков, через добавление и удаление класса `active` у блоков.

```js
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

next.addEventListener('click', function () {
    blocks.forEach(function (val, id) {
        if (val.classList.contains('active')){

            val.classList.remove('active');

        }
    })
})
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="arrow left" id="prev">
      <button>left</button>
    </div>
    <div class="block active" id="block1">
      block1
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="block2">
      block2
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="block3">
      block3
    </div>
    <div class="block" id="block4">
      block4
    </div>
    <div class="arrow right" id="next">
      <button>right</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

и вот после `val.classList.remove('active');`
мне нужно написать `val.classList.add('active');` но уже к следующему элементу массива. B вопрос, как можно это сделать, используя именно цикл `forEach`?

Comment: второй параметр, передаваемый в коллбэк, это индекс текущего элемента, поэтому index+1 - это индекс следующего. Возникает вопрос - что ты хочешь делать если активный элемент - последний?

Comment: Зачем бежать по всем блокам, если нужны только активные?

Comment: @Grundy чтобы найти его местоположение, и изменить следующий/предыдущий

Comment: @Grundy я новичок в js, поэтому делаю как думаю. Если этому есть более простое решение, буду рад увидеть

Comment: @Grundy и активный блок только 1, всего блоков 4. И при нажатии на кнопки, активные блоки сменяются

Comment: @Grundy если активный элемент последний, то происходит переход на первый

Comment: более простое - взять текущий активный сразу и потом взять следующий

Comment: А как найти тот что следующий, если нет его местоположения в общем массиве блоков? Извините если туплю, мне будет проще понять, если напишите пример этого кода

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107396/discussion-between-grundy-and-darkrou).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант без цикла.

```js
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // берем активный блок
  const activeBlock = document.querySelector('.content>.block.active');
  // берем следующий блок
  const nextBlock = activeBlock.nextElementSibling;
  // если следующий элемент - блок, то добавляем ему класс active
  if (nextBlock.classList.contains('block')) {
    nextBlock.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    // иначе добавляем певому блоку класс active
    const firstBlock = document.querySelector('.content>.block');
    firstBlock.classList.add('active');
  }
  // убираем у "старого" блока класс active
  activeBlock.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="arrow left" id="prev">
    <button>left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="block" id="block1">
    block1
  </div>
  <div class="block" id="block2">
    block2
  </div>
  <div class="block" id="block3">
    block3
  </div>
  <div class="block active" id="block4">
    block4
  </div>
  <div class="arrow right" id="next">
    <button>right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: почему так `.content:first-child`, а не просто `.content`?

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за замечание. Сначала хотел сделать с помощью `:first-child` нахождение первого блока, потом заметил что стрелочки на том же уровне, переделал, а `:first-child` забыл убрать :)